# Single quote in bash script curl command keeps getting converted to double quote

Tags: sql, linux, bash, curl

Seen many related posts but nothing has helped me resolve my issue. I have a CURL command in a bash script. The Data element contains a SQL command. The SQL command includes a param that must be single quoted. So, it looks like this:

```
jsonData=$(curl --request POST \
        --url $uribase/Redrock/Query \
        --header 'content-type: application/json' \
        --header 'X-NATIVE-CLIENT: 1' \        
        --data '{"Script":"'"Select Server.ID, Server.ComputerClass, Server.FQDN, Server.Name, Server.SessionType from Server WHERE Server.ComputerClass='Unix' COLLATE NOCASE"'"}')
```

I've tried so many variations on quoting the Server.ComputerClass value to no avail. I can't get it to resolve to ='Unix'. Even tried \u0027 unicode. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try escaping it (eg. `\'Unix\'`)...

Comment: Thanks but debug outputs:... Server.ComputerClass=\'\''Unix\'\'' ...

Comment: Can you show what your final string is supposed to look like?

Comment: Quotes don't nest. It looks like you're trying to use single-quotes inside a single-quoted string, and that won't work.

Comment: @Ill Single quotes don't accept escaped characters.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to quote it correctly, feed it to `curl` from a here document via standard input. Use an array to allow you to organize the options more cleanly as well.

```
curl_opts=( --request POST
            --url "$uribase/Redrock/Query"
            --header 'content-type: application/json'
            --header 'X-NATIVE-CLIENT: 1'
            --data @-
          )
```

The `@-` tells `curl` to read the data from a file named `-`, which is a `curl`-defined alias for standard input.

```
jsonData=$(curl "${curl_opts[@]}" <<EOF
{ "Script": "Select Server.ID, Server.ComputerClass, Server.FQDN, Server.Name, Server.SessionType from Server WHERE Server.ComputerClass='Unix' COLLATE NOCASE"}
EOF
)
```

Comment: Thanks to all above. Every option fails unfortunately. @chepner, tried your method and when I look at the request body submitted in the POST (via curl --trace-ascii), I see (yet again) that the Server.ComputerClass value is munged: => Send data, 158 bytes (0x9e)
0000: {"Script":"Select Server.ID, Server.ComputerClass, Server.FQDN, 
0040: Server.Name, Server.SessionType from Server WHERE Server.Compute
0080: rClass='\''Unix'\'' COLLATE NOCASE"}

Comment: And those issues are ...?

Comment: Hit send too soon. FUll comment in post above.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting gets confusing fast.  Yes, using a file to store the statement will work ; if you prefer not to do that, then here is something you could try.

Create a function :

```
sql_request()
{
  printf "'{"
  printf '"Script"'
  ...
}
```

You get the general idea : break it down in as many pieces as needed ; when you need a single quote enclose it in double quotes, when you need a double quote, enclose it in single quotes.

You can then call that function as needed to get your request :

```
"$(sql_request)"
```

You can even easily feed arguments into this function to change portions of the string.